# configure URLs in system workflow messages

Tags: smarty, system-workflow-messages, pledges

I've discovered that the URL that is created in the Pledge Acknowledgement and Reminder system workflow messages points to our admin site rather than the public site on our Joomla site. In other words, the url starts with "domain.org/administrator/" rather than "domain.org/index.org" This may be a configuration problem somewhere, or perhaps a bug in how Core handles Joomla urls. Any help on how I can fix this?

One fix that I've tried is to just remove the crmURL call in the smarty template, and replace it with text and simple smarty tokens, but I'm not sure how to access the pledge_id in this case.

Joomla 3.9.24, Civi 5.33.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's entirely possible the stock template doesn't account for this. There are some cryptic parameters you can add to crmURL to force a frontend or backend url, respectively: `fe=1` or `fb=1`. (That's not a typo - fe=frontend, fb=forceBackend)

I don't use joomla but if that works for you can you either make a lab ticket at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/-/issues/new or if you can make a PR against core.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed in my research that there at least used to be some additional params for that sort of thing, but I couldn't find any details on those anywhere in the documentation. This would definitely be something to update the template with, as there's never a reason to send out backend links. I'll see if I have the time to run a PR.